# Link embedding in wmd editor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wmd-editor, embedly

How to enable link embedding (preview) in WMD editor? 
Is there any in build editor available with these kind of functionality?

Below screenshot I have taken from [Discourse](http://try.discourse.org/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All StackExchange sites use a modified version of WMD called PageDown https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/ and on the server they use MarkDown C# https://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am aware about pagedown and markdown editor. My question is about embedding multiple url.